# pyqt4 on Linux environment

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4

I am trying to use PyQt4. I have downloaded its LINUX version and trying to install it with Cygwin(because I have windows on my PC and I want to use linux, therefore I am using Cygwin). I don't know how to install it ? please guide me . There is no such file like setup.py, install....what should I do??

Comment: If you're on windows, install the windows build?

Comment: "I want to use linux, therefore I am using Cygwin". Cygwin is not Linux. There is no sense in installing linux version of pyqt on windows with cygwin. use Linux, or use Windows build like delnan says.

Answer (score 2):

PyQt4 and Qt are cross-platform. If you write cross-platform code, you don't need to develop on any specific OS. Testing on different platforms from time to time is a good idea, but good cross-platform code will usually just work.

Don't use any Windows-specific features, Windows-specific code. In particular, don't use `subprocess` unless calling shell commands is part of your app, use `os.path` instead of writing paths yourself, don't hardcode any paths, verify that each library that you're using is cross-platform, and you'd be fine.

And when you're testing on Linux, test on actual Linux. Cygwin is another, different platform. You can try using a virtual machine with VirtualBox.

P.S. You might also look at Nokia's new PySide which has more liberal license than PyQt4 and supports most of what PyQt4 supports with nearly the same interface. It's a bit young, but by the time you complete your application, it would probably be more common.